# Exception because of UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, ios6, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using the UIRefreshControl for the first time and I get an exception during the loading of my refresh control.

Here is my declaration :

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.actualitesTableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

Here are my functions :

```
- (void)refreshView:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(threadAction) withObject:nil];
}

- (void)threadAction {
    [self choixMAJ];
    NSLog(@"OK1");
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    NSLog(@"OK2");
}
```

When I use the choixMAJ() method, it works perfectly.

Everything's going right and the OK2 is logged but after that, when the refresh control disapeared, the app crashed with this error :

```
*** -[__NSArrayM removeObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x655a1a0
```

I don't understand why.. Any ideas ?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't call -endRefreshing on a background thread, for starters. UIKit methods (including that one) should be performed on the main thread. I'm not sure that's actually causing your problem, though.

Comment: You're right. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: The `addSubview:` call is unnecessary.  By simply setting the `refreshControl` property of your `UITableViewController` subclass, you're taking care of that already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Well, you shouldn't call -endRefreshing on a background thread, for starters. UIKit methods (including that one) should be performed on the main thread. I'm not sure that's actually causing your problem, though.

Thanks shusta, it helps me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is correct, and to work around this i did the following.
I setup a timer in the main thread which monitored for a boolean.  When you are ready to stop the refresher... set that boolean to true in your sub-thread.  The timer will see that and call the endRefreshing function from the main thread.